# Build issue with LightGBM 2.2.4, Boost 1.64.0 on Power9 w/GPU

Tags: lightgbm

I am attempting to build LightGBM version 2.2.4  (git hash 5256cda69300d6b83b18180da2992a1e50a6b392) on an IBM Power9 system ("Witherspoon", CPU is a Power System AC922, 8335-GTH) running Red Hat Enterprise Server 7.5 (Maipo).

I am using the RHEL-packaged C compiler, gcc 4.8.5, a local version of cmake, version 3.13.1, and a local installation of Boost version 1.64.0, The system has CUDA 9.2 installed, and I have located the libOpenCL directories and include files.

My configuration operation is (from inside a newly-created build directory in the root of the unpacked LightGBM tree):

```
# export BOOST_ROOT=/share/sw/boost/1_64_0/ 
# cmake3 -DUSE_GPU=1 -DOpenCL_LIBRARY=/usr/lib64/nvidia/libOpenCL.so -DOpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/CL/ .. 
# make
```

The configuration step apparently succeeds, generating a runnable makefile.

The build fails at around 41% with errors from deep in the bowels of Boost:

```
    [ 41%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/treelearner/data_parallel_tree_learner.cpp.o
    In file included from /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/mpl/aux_/integral_wrapper.hpp:22:0,
                     from /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/mpl/int.hpp:20,
                     from /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/mpl/lambda_fwd.hpp:23,
                     from /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/mpl/aux_/na_spec.hpp:18,
                     from /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/mpl/identity.hpp:17,
                     from /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/iterator/detail/enable_if.hpp:11,
                     from /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp:11,
                     from /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:17,
                     from /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp:16,
                     from /wrk/user/src/lightgbm/LightGBM/compute/include/boost/compute/device.hpp:18,
                     from /wrk/user/src/lightgbm/LightGBM/compute/include/boost/compute/context.hpp:19,
                     from /wrk/user/src/lightgbm/LightGBM/compute/include/boost/compute/buffer.hpp:15,
                     from /wrk/user/src/lightgbm/LightGBM/compute/include/boost/compute/core.hpp:18,
                     from /wrk/user/src/lightgbm/LightGBM/src/treelearner/gpu_tree_learner.h:27,
                     from /wrk/user/src/lightgbm/LightGBM/src/treelearner/parallel_tree_learner.h:5,
                     from /wrk/user/src/lightgbm/LightGBM/src/treelearner/data_parallel_tree_learner.cpp:1:
    /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/mpl/vector.hpp:28:18: error: pasting ")" and "20" does not give a valid preprocessing token
         BOOST_PP_CAT(vector, BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE).hpp \
                      ^
    /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:29:34: note: in definition of macro ‘BOOST_PP_CAT_I’
     #    define BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b) a ## b
                                      ^
    /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/mpl/vector.hpp:28:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘BOOST_PP_CAT’
         BOOST_PP_CAT(vector, BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE).hpp \
         ^
    /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/mpl/vector.hpp:36:49: note: in expansion of macro ‘AUX778076_VECTOR_HEADER’
     #   include BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(boost/mpl/vector/AUX778076_VECTOR_HEADER)
                                                     ^
    In file included from /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/math/policies/policy.hpp:14:0,
                     from /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/math/special_functions/math_fwd.hpp:28,
                     from /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/math/special_functions/sign.hpp:17,
                     from /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/lexical_cast/detail/inf_nan.hpp:34,
                     from /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical_streams.hpp:63,
                     from /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical.hpp:54,
                     from /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/lexical_cast/try_lexical_convert.hpp:42,
                     from /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:32,
                     from /wrk/user/src/lightgbm/LightGBM/compute/include/boost/compute/detail/meta_kernel.hpp:23,
                     from /wrk/user/src/lightgbm/LightGBM/compute/include/boost/compute/iterator/buffer_iterator.hpp:26,
                     from /wrk/user/src/lightgbm/LightGBM/compute/include/boost/compute/algorithm/detail/copy_on_device.hpp:18,
                     from /wrk/user/src/lightgbm/LightGBM/compute/include/boost/compute/algorithm/copy.hpp:26,
                     from /wrk/user/src/lightgbm/LightGBM/compute/include/boost/compute/container/vector.hpp:32,
                     from /wrk/user/src/lightgbm/LightGBM/src/treelearner/gpu_tree_learner.h:28,
                     from /wrk/user/src/lightgbm/LightGBM/src/treelearner/parallel_tree_learner.h:5,
                     from /wrk/user/src/lightgbm/LightGBM/src/treelearner/data_parallel_tree_learner.cpp:1:
    /share/sw/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/mpl/vector.hpp:36:73: fatal error: boost/mpl/__attribute__((altivec(vector__)))/__attribute__((altivec(vector__)))20.hpp: No such file or directory
     #   include BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(boost/mpl/vector/AUX778076_VECTOR_HEADER)
```

From the messages, it looks like some preprocessor string manipulation has gone wrong, it's maybe trying to find the "vector20.hpp" file in the boot/mpl/vector include directory, but the BOOST_PP_CAT operation has gone wrong, so it's failing to construct a proper filename? Also, the "altivec" is implicated, the Power9 CPU is altivec-capable, maybe an additional header or compiler switch is required?

I can successfully build (with warnings) on a Debian 9 "stretch" system with x86_64 architecture and CUDA 9.1 (for the libOpenCL stuff), with the Debian-packaged Boost version 1.62.

I also tried building the Power9 version against Boost 1.69, and against Boost 1.62 (the one that worked on Debian), and got the same errors in the same place.

Help?

Comment: Minor addition, I have come back to this, and tried re-building everything (except the libOpenCL stuff) with a newer compiler, gcc-7, and I see the same behavior.

Comment: Additional info, I have now attempted a build of both Boost 1.64.0 and LightGBM on Power9 with gcc-6. I am still getting the same behavior in the same place.

Comment: Still flailing on this. I have now tried building it under Ubuntu 18.04 on ppc64el -- I am more familiar with Debian derivs, and have root on the system, so things are a bit easier.

But, the build still falls over, in the same place, in the same way.

I found a possibly-related complaint from several years ago about header files substituting '__attribute__((altivec((vector__)))' for 'vector' by default on ppc, but no additional diagnostic clues? (Is this actually my issue? How to turn it off?)

Comment: Found a reference to "that horrible macro" that makes this substitution on [another site](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1211975), still no answer.

Comment: I now have a work-around, but I'm not thrilled with it -- if I set the CMAKE_CXX_CFLAGS variable to include "-mno-altivec", it will build, but the price is zillions of warnings about how I am foregoing all the cool optimizations.

I'm not (yet) setting this as an answer, because I don't like it very much, I'm still hoping for a way to use the Power9's CPU features without bad substitutions in the header-file paths.

Comment: So it turns out this exact issue has already been [raised](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1905)
and closed by the LightGBM team. Their opinion is that the compilation failure is an altivec/boost interaction that they are powerless to address, and also that there is no OpenCL GPU support on the Power architecture, so even if you could build it, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is addressed in an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1905) on the LightGBM github, which I somehow missed on my initial search.

This build attempt is misguided.

The compilation problem is apparently an altivec/boost interaction, and there's no OpenCL GPU support on the Power architecture, and LightGBM is OpenCL under the hood, so the effort is doomed in any case.